# systemd Unable to find Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, centos, systemctl

I'm facing a strange behaviour on a Centos Dist trying to run a bootable jar created with spring boot.

If I run the jar app from the shell it runs perfectly

[image]

When running the app with a service created with the following config:

```
[Unit]
Description=app
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/foo/bar/app.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
~
```

I keep getting the error "Unable to find Java"

[image]

I checked the $PATH and $JAVA_HOME properties and they are set up correctly (I don't think this adds more information because the bootable jar runs correctly without beeing a service)

What I'm doing wrong? Been messing around this problem for 3 days and it's driving me mad.

Comment: where did you set the PATH?

Comment: how are you starting the service? if you are running with sudo than make sure those variables are also configured for root user other wise the current user.

Comment: Doing that:

echo $PATH

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Comment: I'm running it with systemctl start foo.service. The user i'm running all the time is root.

Comment: systemd does not run in user context, the PATH is not inherited. Add the PATH to the `[Service]` section of the `.service` file: `Environment=PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`, and reload the service (`systemctl daemon-reload`), then start the service. This should work around the problem. The underlying problem is that java is not OS integrated (there's no java in the default path).

Comment: working like a charm @Petesh you made my day. Add it as answer and I flag it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The long and short of the issue is that systemd does not run services in the same context as the user shell, and the mechanism used for running .jar files directly uses the `PATH` variable to determine the location of the JRE for running the jar.

If java was on the default systemd path, then the service would start by default. The [default path for systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#%24PATH) definitely does not contain the path that you're specifying for java.

To address the PATH variable not being set sufficiently, we're going to update the service configuration with a `PATH` environment variable more suitable to it. To accomplish this, we need to add a `Environment` variable to the `[Service]` section of the service definition file.

```
[Unit]
Description=app
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Environment=PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ExecStart=/foo/bar/app.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then we reload systemd (`systemctl daemon-reload`), and we should be able to start the service (`systemctl start blah.service`).

It would probably be significantly easier if the jre you want to use is integrated into the OS; it saves having to futz around with the PATH, and would survive upgrades to java, which would alter the path, requiring an update to the service definition - there's a pretty [good guide here](https://www.tecmint.com/install-java-on-centos-rhel-fedora/) as to how to install it, system integrated:

- Download rpm

  - `wget --no-check-certificate -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/14.0.2+12/205943a0976c4ed48cb16f1043c5c647/jdk-14.0.2_linux-x64_bin.rpm`
- Install locally

  - `yum localinstall jdk-14.0.2_linux-x64_bin.rpm`
- Use `alternatives` to configure java

  - `alternatives --config java`
- Check after setting

  - `java -version`

Comment: thanks again @Petesh. I have a question regarding the other solution which is to install integrated in the OS. In our case I think it's already done and it was not working. When I run java -version it returns correctly the "JDK"


[root@TOMCATQAPP05 osaapi]# java --version
openjdk 14.0.2 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: By 'integrated into the os' I mean that it is on the default PATH for systemd - i.e. if you run `type -p java` it should yield a short path to java, most likely `/usr/bin/java` rather than `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin/java`

Comment: Ok got it @Petesh. I've been searching how our system administrator installed the java and it's different from your instructions, that could lead to why it's not integrated. I will try to fix it so as you suggest we don't need to have the path set in the .service file. Thanks for the help, I'm a developer and have minium experience with this kind of configurations.